# How to Select Database for an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have multiple SQL databases and I need to insert data into one of them. I am not sure how to select the database.

The following code was working when I only had 1 database, but now that there are multiple databases, this code no longer works.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, first_name, last_name, email, 
password, hash, avatar) "
        . "VALUES 
('$username','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password', '$hash', 
'$avatar')";
```

I want to write the above data into a table in a specific database.

Comment: Database is MySQL, I think. I'm not a coder.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it while connection or just:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO databasename.users (username, first_name, last_name, email, password, hash, avatar) " 
. "VALUES ('$username','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password', '$hash', '$avatar')";
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is not writing into the database. How do I set the connection?

Comment: it depends on how is your connection.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these might work

1. Use '`DBName.users`' in the query instead of '`users`'.
2. Execute the query '`use DBName;`' before the insert query.

Comment: @DanielE. That’s pretty much independent of the programming language, it depends on the driver and the rdbms.

Comment: It's not working. If I have to set the connection, where would I do that?